# Returning a loop, with clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

Trying make this so that a name will pop up when each item is clicked. I gave each element an ID, but I'm obviously missing something. Code as written, wondering what my brain is missing (ie. I think I'm supposed to be making a variable, but I'm not sure?):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var clicks= ["h1", "h2", "p1", "img", "p2", "li1", "li2", "li3", "li4", "li5", "p3"]

    clicks.forEach(function(element) {
        var name = $(" ") {
            $(clicks).click(function);
            alert("I'm a "+name+"!")
        });
    });
});
```

ETA: Also wondering what to do with the "element" I put after function. Gosh, this is a mess.

Comment: please tag this with the language you're using (javascript?) for more people to see it

Comment: What is `name`? Is it just the element's name or something else? It would help if you attached some example HTML, or even better if you created an example on http://jsbin.com

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think there are many ways to skin that cat.  But using the same program structure as you have already something like this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var clicks= ["#h1", "#h2", "#p1", "img", "#p2", "#li1", "#li2", "#li3", "#li4", "#li5", "#p3"]

    clicks.forEach(function(element) {
        $(element).click(function() {
           alert("I'm a "+element+"!");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I would like that to work, but I tried, and it doesn't. My concern is that "element" doesn't give any information. I can't figure out how to make it callback the information for what each element is. I mean, if I want it to say "I'm a paragraph!" I thought I needed a variable. I dunno. I'm lost.

Comment: I just tested it and it does seem to work.  Note that I was missing parens after the second function -- ().  I've edited the code in the original message.  Does it still not work for you?

Comment: Okay, yes. Now it works. I realized that I had those as just their element names, but I had tagged all these elements with an id. I had put their ids in an array, but had not added the #. I fixed that, and now it works. HOWEVER. It pops up with "I'm a #p1" Instead of "I'm a paragraph". How would I do that? Would I need to go ahead and create variable of some sort for that?

Comment: This solution is wrong - because you're looping through `element`s, when you finally fire the click handler (long after the loop has finished), `element` will always be the last element in the array. (p3). Javascript is asynchronous, so you need to pay attention to scope.

Comment: What you might do is change your array to a list of objects instead of strings.. like this:
var clicks = [{selector: '#h1', name: 'header1'}, {selector: 'p1', name: 'paragraph 1' }];

Comment: then when you iterate it would be clicks.foreach(function(e){ $(e.selector).click(function() { alert( e.name ); });

Comment: You can use an object if you want to map the IDs to names. See my edited answer below.

Comment: Actually, jesse, the function creates a closure so element will be what it should when the event fires.

Answer (score 0):

I would think you would be better served simply eliminating your `clicks` array and foreach construct and using a selector for the elements you are interested in:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var selectorString = 'h1, h2, p1, img, p2, li1, li2, li3, li4, li5, p3';

    $(selectorString).click(function() {
        alert("I'm a " + this.tagName + "!");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, here's some annotated code that will do what you want:

```
// same as $(document).ready(), but shorter:
$(function(){
  var clicks = ["h1" /* etc... */];

  // this just iterates through the strings you set above, so you'll have strings inside the loop.
  clicks.forEach(function(selector){
    // any variable you set here would be available inside the click handler, but note that because javascript is asynchronous, this would not be what you expect.

    // if you're looking for the element, by ID, you'll need to use '#id' instead of 'id'. I append '#' to the beginning so it's using IDs.
    $('#' + selector).on('click',function(el){
      // this is now a jquery reference to the element.
      var element = $(el);
      // you can ask the element for it's id here, and because it's in scope, it will be correct.
      var id = element.attr('id');
      alert('I am a ' + id);
    });
  });
});
```

**edit:**

If you want to use a map to identify your IDs, here's how that code would look:

```
// same as $(document).ready(), but shorter:
$(function(){
  var clickMap = {
    "h1" : "header one",
    "p1" : "paragraph one"
    /* etc */
  };

  // this just iterates through the strings you set above, so you'll have strings inside the loop.
  // we'll use Object.keys to get just the keys from the map, which will be your IDs.
  Object.keys(clickMap).forEach(function(selector){
    // any variable you set here would be available inside the click handler, but note that because javascript is asynchronous, this would not be what you expect.

    // if you're looking for the element, by ID, you'll need to use '#id' instead of 'id'. I append '#' to the beginning so it's using IDs.
    $('#' + selector).on('click',function(el){
      // this is now a jquery reference to the element.
      var element = $(el);
      // you can ask the element for it's id here, and because it's in scope, it will be correct.
      var id = element.attr('id');
      // we'll use the value from our click map now, to print "paragraph one" for "p1", etc.
      alert('I am a ' + clickMap[id]);
    });
  });
});
```